# MoveToDesktop for Windows 11?

Tags: windows, desktop-environment

There is a nice tool, MoveToDesktop, for Windows 10, which allows one to move a window to another (virtual) desktop, but it does not seem to work for Windows 11.

Is there a similar tool for Windows 11 (22H2)?

I have tried various Google searches, without success.

I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 0):

I use [VirtuaWin](https://virtuawin.sourceforge.io/).  I am not associate with it in any way.

> VirtuaWin is a virtual desktop manager for the Windows operating system (all recent versions). A virtual desktop manager lets you organize applications over several virtual desktops (also called ‘workspaces’). Virtual desktops are very common in Unix/Linux, and once you get accustomed to using them, they become an essential part of a productive workflow.

It supports a variable number of windows, I use 2x2

[image]

It supports hotkeys for moving from one desktop to another or to shift teh curretn window to another desktop.

[image]

You can set up rules about such as

- which window moves with you as you navigate
- or which window always opens on a particular desktop.

There about a dozen addons to enhance it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to install it, but only got "VirtualWin Error: Failed to register hotkey 5, check hotkeys". Do you know how to fix this?